# Natural language processing library for auto-tagging (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, nlp

Dose anyone know of any good libraries out there for .NET that could help pull keywords out of blocks of natural language.

I'm basically trying to strip out stop words and ignore tenses, plurals and generally    find words that are essentially the same.

Some abilities to find synonyms would be nice, especially if it includes things like business/technology/non-dictionary words.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for a good auto-tagging library for some time. I haven't found one that has all the features you need, but for creating basic text summaries and keyword lists, the C# port of the [OpenTextSummarizer](http://ots.codeplex.com/) isn't too bad.

Comment: looks interesting, I'll have to investigate when I get a bit of time. Thanks :-)